# How to use multiple labels as targets in Neural Net Pattern Recognition Toolbox?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, pattern-recognition

I am trying to use the Neural Net Pattern Recognition toolbox in MATLAB for recognizing different types of classes in my dataset. I have a 21392 x 4 table, with the columns 1-3 which I would like to use as predictors and the 4th column has the labels with 14 different categories (strings like Angry, Sad, Happy, Neutral etc.). It seems that the Neural Net Pattern Recognition toolbox, unlike the MATLAB Classification Learner toolbox doesn't allow me to import the table and automatically extract the predictors and responses from it. Moreover, I am unable to either specify the inputs and targets to the neural network manually as it isn't showing up in the options.

I looked into the examples like the Iris Dataset, Wine Dataset, Cancer Dataset etc., but all of them only have 2-3 classes as outputs which are being Identified (and encoded in binary like 000, 010, 011 etc.) and the labels are not string type unlike mine like Angry, Sad, Happy, Neutral etc. (total 14 different classes). I would like to know how I can use my table as input to the neural network pattern recognition toolbox, or otherwise, any way in which I can extract the data from my table and use it in the toolbox. I am new to using the toolbox, so any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step to use the Neural Net Pattern Recognition Toolbox is to convert the table to a numeric array, as neural networks work only with numeric arrays, not other datatypes directly. Considering the table as `my_table`, it can be converted to a numeric array using

```
my_table_array = table2array(my_table);
```

From `my_table_array`, the inputs (predictors) and outputs/targets can be extracted. But, it is imperative to mention that the inputs and outputs need to be transposed (as the data is needed to be in column format for the toolbox, each column is one datapoint, and each row is the feature), which can easily be accomplished using:-

```
inputs = inputs'; %(now of dimensions 3x21392)
labels = labels'; %(now of dimensions 1x21392)
```

The string type labels (categorical) can be converted to numeric values using a one-hot encoding technique with `categorical`, followed by `ind2vec`:

```
my_table_vector = ind2vec(double(categorical(labels)));
```

Now, the my_table_vector (final targets) and inputs (final input predictors) can easily be fed to the neural network and used for classification/prediction of the target labels.